# What nix channel is subscribed to by default

Tags: nix, nixos

I installed the nix package manager on my machine (macOS 10.12.6 Sierra) several weeks ago.

I want to update mylocal nixpkgs collection to bring it in sync with any upstream updates in the channel. My understanding is that this can be achieved by running: `nix-channel --update`. However when I run this I get the following output:

`unpacking channels...
created 0 symlinks in user environment`

Suggesting no expressions were updated in the channels my system is subscribed to. If I run `nix-channel --list` I don't see any channels listed. What channel is my system subscribed to by default? and should I expect it to be listed?

Is it the case that generally `nix-channel --update` will only produce local changes if I have modified the channels I'm subscribed to or if I'm subscribed to the unstable channel?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**The following might be specific to OSX:**

Nix channels are managed on a per-user basis ([source](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Nix_Channels)). `nix-channel --list`'s output is empty because by default you are not subscribed to any channels - only root is subscribed to `nixpkgs-unstable` ([source](https://github.com/NixOS/nix/blob/6e0989685ab2e7c0e24aafeaaa3f389289c9684b/scripts/install-darwin-multi-user.sh#L580)).

You can run `nix-channel --list` as root to see his subscriptions. But

1. do not run it through `sudo` (see: https://github.com/NixOS/nix/issues/1548) and
2. do not use a simple `sudo su` because it doesn't load /etc/profile ([source](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/43693)) and thus will not have the nix env variables set up ([variables-setup](https://github.com/NixOS/nix/blob/6e0989685ab2e7c0e24aafeaaa3f389289c9684b/scripts/install-darwin-multi-user.sh#L731)).

Working example:

```
    user$ nix-channel --list

    user$ sudo su -
    root# nix-channel --list
    nixpkgs https://nixos.org/channels/nixpkgs-unstable
```

Comment: I had the same problem with a multi-user installation on Ubuntu.  Thanks for the solution!  It helped me.

Answer (score 4):

Your `nix-channel --update` suggests that you have zero channels in your channel list, not zero packages. You can see your channel configuration with `nix-channel --list`. You probably need to configure a channel.

The Nix install script currently configures a single channel with the name `nixpkgs`:

```
"$nix/bin/nix-channel" --add https://nixos.org/channels/nixpkgs-unstable
```

So that's the default channel and it should be listed in `nix-channel --list` after installation, until you `nix-channel --remove nixpkgs` or `rm ~/.nix-channels`.

The `nix-channel` command only updates your Nix expressions. It will not update any package installations. It will only affect future invocations of `nix-build`, `nix-env` and everything else that uses `$NIX_PATH`. (It resembles `apt-get update` in this respect, or `brew update`, except `nix-channel` will not update the installed version of Nix.)

Comment: Thanks Robert, I think my terminology was slightly off - I was using the term "packages" interchangeably with "expressions". I have updated my post accordingly. `nix-channel --list` does not list any channels for me. Does this suggest that something is miss-configured on my system? I have not added/removed any channels since installation. When `nix-channel --update` reports `created 0 symlinks in user environment` does this mean zero expressions were updated upstream? (not what I would expect for the unstable channel - given it's setup for continuous builds).

Comment: The `created 0 symlinks in user environment` message indicates that it has built an empty environment for your `~/.nix-defexpr/channels`. That makes sense because your configuration (`nix-channel --list`) is empty. I suggest running `nix-channel --add https://nixos.org/channels/nixpkgs-unstable` to fix your configuration.

Comment: Thanks Robert, that all makes total sense. As always your help is very greatly appreciated :)